# chown /dev by mistake

Tags: devices, chown

This is a RedHat system running a postgres database.  Nothing seems to have broken.

Do I need to request a restore?  That would destroy a day's worth of work, so I'm not eager to do that.

A couple of things I've read that would perhaps fix things, but I've never used, don't know much about, etc.

udevadm trigger

/sbin/MAKEDEV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reboot, dev will be back as it was, it's not actual files, just devices, although there maybe some symbolic links there good chmod ignores them :)

**EDIT: Just put my money where my mouth is...**

```
find /dev -exec ls -la '{}' \; > /home/mike/dev-perms1
sudo chmod -Rv 777 /dev
sudo reboot
find /dev -exec ls -la '{}' \; > /home/mike/dev-perms2
```

same... :)

ps... make sure you only chmoded /dev... if you chmoded some other dir you may have issues...

Comment: It was chown, not chmod, but I've put in a reboot request and if that fixes things I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

chown dev is not dangerous,but for safety
install a clean virtual machine
(of course same system,rhel in this
case)
and copy the correct permission 
from there.
chmod is a little more dangerous,but
a easy solution,make usually a backup
with cpio of all dirs,if you make something
wrong you can restore from cpio archive,
or use rsync.